# progressive web app not working on production server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, next.js

The platform I am using for developing my project is nextjs. I am using serverless technology for deployment.Google cloud function with firebase hosting is used for serverless deployment. Deployment is working fine. The only problem is my app does not show 'Install this app' icon on the browser address bar. It shows up only if I switch to offline mode by going to Application/Service Workers on console. Manifest and everything is configured properly. No issue is shown.

[image]

For offline web app feature, I have used `next-pwa` library

Here is how I have used

```
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const optimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [optimizedImages],
  withPWA({
    pwa: {
     dest: "public",
    },
  }),
);
```

I have set sw.js file on firebase.json as well

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**", ".hooks"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/sw.js",
        "headers": [{ "key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache" }]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**/**",
        "function": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
```

server.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const next = require('next')

var dev = false
var app = next({ dev, conf: { distDir: '.next' } })
var handle = app.getRequestHandler()

exports.next = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res))
})
```

Have i missed anything to make my app offline application?

Comment: could you show us your manifest? did you linked your manifest? `<link rel="manifest" src="./mainfest.webmanifest" />` is your `fetch()` handler configure propertly?

Comment: Currently I am on my mobile. I can't share you code for now. But yes I have linked manifest file. It's working properly as it shows up on console area. I have setup icons of required sizes and app theme as well.

Comment: It works offline in the case of network disconnection. But it asks for install app only when the network is disconnected not when it's online. For API I have used graphql.

Comment: Did you add `window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", function(e){ console.log("fires"); })` and checked if it fires

Comment: Do i have to use that to make it work?

Comment: its not essential, but you can check with it if the event fires that asking you for installation

Comment: it seems like beforeinstallprompt is not listened. I used that listener on _app.js inside componentDidMount. It didn't console "fires".

Comment: did it fire when u was offline?